# Преобразование даты и времени clickhouse

Tags: datetime, clickhouse

есть значение, например `56` секунд в формате `int64`
хочу преобразовать это в формат `00:00:56`
использую предварительно функцию перевода в датувремя `toDateTime`

и почему то получаю `1970-01-01 06:00:56`

6 часов это так понимаю часовой пояс

если сделать разницу, через - `Interval 6 hour` то получаю вообще `2106-02-07 06:28:16`

в общем вопрос, как получить  хотя бы `1970-01-01 00:00:56`